# When to use te form vs. で

Tags: grammar, particles, て-form

So 「バスに乗って、会社に行きます。」means "I go to work by bus."
Yet, 「バスで会社に行きます。」also means "I go to work by bus."

Do these two sentences convey the exact same meaning, or is there some kind of nuance that exists when using で instead of te form (for this kind of situation in general)?

Comment: Usually we say 「バスで会社に行きます」or simply 「バスで行きます」.  Though 「バスに乗って、会社に行きます」is substantially the same meaning but it sounds verbose in daily conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. 「バスに乗って、会社に行きます。」
> 2. 「バスで会社に行きます。」

Indeed, the two sentences virtually mean the same thing, but I can't generalize anything here. #**1** literally says "I get on a bus, **and** go to the office," and the #**2** literally says "I go to the office **by** bus."

テ形 (te-form) is the form to continue the sentence. て is like conjunction 'and'.
で has many usages, but basically indicates a means, like the preposition 'by'.

Answer (score 0):

Those are practically same sentences. 
But in theory latter could mean that you are driving the bus by yourself. That is something you can know from the context.